# Regex split large text

Tags: regex

I have text which looks like this:

```
HEADING

Some random text which is not capitalized. Heading are always in their own line and capitalized.

HEADINGHHHH
Some other random text.
```

I would like to split this text into two parts:

```
1.part:
 HEADING

Some random text which is not capitalized. Heading are always in their own line and capitalized.
```

AND

```
2.part : HEADINGHHHH
Some other random text.
```

So basically, I would like to "split" by capitalized headings, and each object must contain heading with text under it, till the next heading.

I tried

```
(([A-Z]+\\s?)+)$
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I cant really figure out how to do it, Iam new to regex..

Comment: Which language/engine are you using?

Comment: I have tried C# and ruby.

Comment: Does it have to be a `split()` or can it be a global match?

Comment: Doesnt have to be a split, but must be regex..

Comment: HEADING can be any capitalized word, such as CAR, WINDOWS, RANDOMTEXT...

Answer (score 1):

The following [works](https://regex101.com/r/qS1aD6/1):

```
/\G([A-Z]+\n+[\s\S]*?(?=\n+[A-Z]+\n|$))\n*/g
```

I.e. A ‘heading‘ and everything following it (non-greedily) up until there's a new ‘heading’.

Note that it's a global match, rather than a `split()`.  Note also that it uses a look-ahead, so whichever engine you use will have to support that.

<sup><sup>It's something of a hack, so if you can use a line-based parser, perhaps in combination with regex, I would recommend that.</sup></sup>

---

An alternative is to use a `split()` that can save the delimiters (I know Perl's can, and IIRC so can JavaScript's).

E.g in Perl:

```perl
split /^([A-Z]+)$/m, $text;
```

This will, however, put a heading in every other element in the list, and their contents in the other elements.

Yet another alternative is to split with a look-ahead, e.g. `/^(?=[A-Z]+$)/m`.

Comment: How would I use that in ruby or C#?

Comment: @NejcLovrencic I'm afraid I have no idea, sorry. I've never used either of those.